# Why Oracle SP with parameter Not Working with SSRS Report

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, odac

I am trying to build SSRS report which using Oracle SP as backend to get data from Oracle DB. SP have only one input parameter & out put parameter ref cursor. On my client machine this is working fine but once I deployed on SSRS server it giving me error.
But same SP without any parameter or with one input parameter working on SSRS server
ODAC Driver Installed on SSRS server.
Error Message:
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'get_name'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: I don't know SSRS, but - if this stored procedure has one IN and one OUT parameter, why wouldn't you "convert" it to a **function**? Because, if it is a procedure, you need to declare *something* (a local variable?) which will accept value returned by the OUT parameter.

Comment: Out parameter is defined ref cursor in oracle stored procedure

Comment: It's been a while since I had to connect to Oracle but I do remember these uissues were *usually* related to client or driver versions. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534669/error-while-executing-oracle-stored-procedure-in-ssrs-pls-00306-wrong-number-o or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933978/unable-to-call-a-oracle-stored-procedure-from-ssrs-report-builder-3-0 or numerous other similar ones.